# Simbolo desconhecido javascript

Tags: javascript

Galera, estou aprendendo javascript e baixei o Olw Carousel e fui ver o js e no inicio do script tem esse trecho `;(function($, window, document, undefined)` o que me intrigou foi esse ponto e virgula no inicio, gostaria de saber o que ele representa no inicio. Obrigado

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esse `;` é uma salvaguarda caso esse script seja misturado com outros.

Se tiveres por exemplo código mal formatado que não termine com `;` e se juntares ambos os códigos sem quebra de linha o browser pode interpretar como o mesmo código e gerar erros.